# ARIMA equation from R output

Tags: r, arima

I have three ARIMA models by these output by R. After using `auto.arima` there is 3 models that R told me which (1,1,0), (0,0,1), and (1,1,1)

According to these models

[image: ARIMA Model (p,d,q)]

how could I represent the syntax below to input the parameters into the models?

```
> fit110 <- arima(Diff1, order = c(1,1,0), method = "ML")
> fit110

Call:
arima(x = Diff1, order = c(1, 1, 0), method = "ML")

Coefficients:
          ar1
      -0.3857
s.e.   0.0725

sigma^2 estimated as 13217:  log likelihood = -992.42,  aic = 1986.83
> coeftest(fit110) #ok

z test of coefficients:

     Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)    
ar1 -0.385688   0.072524  -5.318 1.049e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> fit011 <-arima(Diff1, order = c(0,1,1), method = "ML")
> fit011

Call:
arima(x = Diff1, order = c(0, 1, 1), method = "ML")

Coefficients:
          ma1
      -1.0000
s.e.   0.0192

sigma^2 estimated as 9031:  log likelihood = -964.22,  aic = 1930.44
> coeftest(fit011) #ok

z test of coefficients:

     Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)    
ma1 -0.999994   0.019179 -52.139 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> fit111 <-arima(Diff1, order = c(1,1,1), method = "ML")
> fit111

Call:
arima(x = Diff1, order = c(1, 1, 1), method = "ML")

Coefficients:
         ar1     ma1
      0.1400  -1.000
s.e.  0.0788   0.018

sigma^2 estimated as 8873:  log likelihood = -962.66,  aic = 1929.31
> coeftest(fit111) #ok

z test of coefficients:

     Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)    
ar1  0.139953   0.078766   1.7768   0.0756 .  
ma1 -0.999999   0.017968 -55.6541   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I am so sorry for my English. If you guys need more information please let me know.

Comment: Hi Cakar and Welcome to CV! Your question is not clear. Please add more details to help clarify your question.

Comment: Search *ARIMA model equation*, perhaps add *R*, and you will find a dozen of relevant threads.